# Why Order Grand Total isn't showing in Magento Report and Last 5 Order Grid?

Tags: php, magento

I programmatically created orders in Magento. Everything looks fine except orders that are created programmatically don't have a grand total in last 5 order grid on my dashboard. These order totals also aren't accounted in daily sales report.

Please check screenshot below.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/62230/429611/U4dlMkGkwku8v3S/1.png

```
$order->setSubtotal($orderSubTotal)
                    ->setBaseSubtotal($orderSubTotal)
                    ->setTaxAmount($orderTax)
                    ->setBaseTaxAmount($orderTax)
                    ->setGrandTotal($grandTotal)
                    ->setBaseGrandTotal($grandTotal);
```

The HTML markup for that grid is found in **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/dashboard/grid.phtml** on line 53

```
<?php echo (($_html = $_column->getRowField($_item)) != '' ? $_html : '&nbsp;') ?>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem and they also dont show up in the revenue reports.

Answer (score 2):

To have the orders shown in the dashboard with the correct revenue value, the field `base_to_global_rate` in `sales_flat_order` table must be set to `1.0000`.

I did this in the database directly but I guess it'll work in the import process aswell.

To be very sure I also set `base_to_order_rate` (also `sales_flat_order` table) to `1.0000` aswell.

They now show in the dashboard and in the reports (after re-generating them) aswell!